# how to sum data from multiple columns with specific index

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a data set and some index like below

[image]

[image]

I'd like to sum column 2, 5 and 7 (A1, A4 and A6 in data set). Note that `na` is also included in this column. How should I prepare a formula for this type of calculation. Thanks

Comment: do you want to sum row wise or column wise?

Comment: by the way you haven't accepted your last three questions, and this community is helping you providing answers. Please spend sometime accepting some of the answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *no excel version constraints as per tag listed in the question*, then you can use the following in cell `G1` to sum by columns, if you need by row, then replace `BYCOL` with `BYROW`:

```
=BYCOL(CHOOSECOLS(B2:D3,TOCOL(E2:E4,2)), LAMBDA(x, SUM(TOCOL(x,2))))
```

Here a sample output:
[image: excel output]

It deals in cases we have `#N/A` values in column selection as well as in the data to sum, via `TOCOL` function, using the second input argument.